# Tensorflow: Identifying the final state in MultiRNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to TF and I am trying to implement multiple GRU cells into the NN. However, I am unable to identify the final state of the MultiRNN cell.

For instance, when I use the following code:

```
num_units = [128, 128]
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 134])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None]) 
embedding_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([153, 128], -1.0, 1.0))
embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix, x) 
cells = [tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_units=n) for n in num_units]
cell_type = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=cells, state_is_tuple=True)
cell_type = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell=cell_type, output_keep_prob=0.75)
_, (encoding, _) = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell_type, embeddings, dtype=tf.float32)
```

The output of the final line of code is:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'rnn/transpose_1:0' shape=(?, 134, 128) dtype=float32>, (<tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_3:0' shape=(?, 128) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'rnn/while/Exit_4:0' shape=(?, 128) dtype=float32>))
```

I believe that the format is:

> **Output Format**: (a,[b, c])

The documentation says that the output is in the format (output, state=[batch_size, cell.state_size]). However, I am unable to identify which of these is the final state of this memory cell. I think that it should be b.

Also, when I run the same code above with 4 GRU cells:

```
num_units = [128, 128, 128, 128]
```

The output is even more confusing:

> **Output Format**: (a,[b, c, d, e])

I am confused about which one of the above is the final memory state which I could then process further for loss calculation and making predictions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have found the answer from [here](https://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-ii.html), it is the state of the last cell in the MultiRNN stack. The following code will easily extract the appropriate one depending on the dimensions that have been fed into num_units:

```
num_units = [128, 128, 128, 128]
rnn_output, final_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell_type, embeddings, dtype=tf.float32)
encoding = final_states[len(num_units)-1] # For GRU & RNN
encoding = final_states[len(num_units)-1][0] # For LSTM
```